# Running node.js code in Excel user-defined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel-udf

It would be nice if one can run node.js code inside Excel user-defined functions. Something like using js code like VBA. 
I googled for solutions but cannot find any. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can (eg) use a `ScriptControl` object from VBA to run javascript, and more-recent version(s) of excel support some level of js scripting - https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application  But that's not really the same thing as running node.js

Comment: At the moment Office-JS addins do not support UDFs: but see Uservoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/6936956-add-user-defined-function-support-to-the-apps-for

Comment: Do you want to use packages from npm?

Comment: @Raymond Lu, I think that's usually unavoidable when using node.js

Comment: I would like to suggest a hacky way: Make a node server on your localhost and call the API endpoint using VBA HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you want to use packages from NPM. You could use webpack to combine all the stuff to one js file, it should work.

webpack as a static module bundler for modern JavaScript applications. When webpack processes your application, it internally builds a dependency graph which maps every module your project needs and generates one or more bundles. you could refers to [this document](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

You could also refer to a sample, [Yeoman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart), the Yeoman generator creates a Node.js Office Add-in project. it use webpack combine all files into one js file.

Comment: office JS code cannot be run in VBA, but you can call Excel Graph API in VBA